# Error when running page with mongo, node.js and socket.io

Tags: node.js, macos, mongodb, socket.io

I'm new to using mongo and having difficulties with set-up on local OSX server.

When I run node app.js my page appears on  http://127.0.0.1:3000/ but I get this error:

```
  Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=************. socket.io.js:5325:0

The connection to ws://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=*************** was interrupted while the page was loading.
```

and when I refresh the page in firefox I get Unable to connect server at 127.0.0.1:3000. and the following error in terminal:

```
a user connected
/Users/******/express_intro/node_modules/mongodb/lib/url_parser.js:15
if(url.indexOf("mongodb://") != 0)
    ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
   at module.exports (/Users/******/express_intro/node_modules/mongodb   /lib/url_parser.js:15:9)
at Function.MongoClient.connect (/Users/******/express_intro/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:95:16)
at Namespace.<anonymous> (/Users/******/express_intro/app.js:48:8)
at Namespace.emit (events.js:107:17)
at Namespace.emit (/Users/******/express_intro/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:205:10)
at /Users/******/express_intro/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:172:14
at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

Here is the app.js

```
var express= require('express');
var bodyParser=require('body-parser');
var path=require('path');
var app=express();
var mongo=require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var http = require('http'); //the variable doesn't necessarily have to be named http

//configure app
app.set('port',process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('view engine','jade');
app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'views'));
//use middleware

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


//define routes
var todoItems=[
  {id:1,desc:'foo'},
  {id:2,desc:'bar'},
  {id:3,desc:'baz'}
];

app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.render('index',{
   title:'My App',
   items:todoItems
  });
});

var serve=http.createServer(app);
var io=require('socket.io')(serve);
serve.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Ready on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
io.on('connection',function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
    mongo.connect(process.env.CUSTOMCONNSTR_MONGOLAB_URI,function(err,db){
     if(err){
        console.warn(err.message);
     }
     else{
        var collection=db.collection('chat messages')
        var stream=collection.find().sort().limit(10).stream();
        stream.on('data',function(chat){
            console.log('emitting chat');
            socket.emit('chat',chat.content);
        });
     }

   });
});
```

Here is the client code

```
  //var socket=io();
  var socket = io('http://localhost:3000/'); 


$('#send-message-btn').click(function(){
var msg=$('#message-box').val();
socket.emit('chat',msg);
$('#messages').append($('<p>').text(msg));
$('#message-box').val('');
return false;
});
socket.on('chat',function(msg){
 $('#message').append($('<p>').text(msg));
});
```

I also get this on loading the page first time

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure, that your environment variable is set ( process.env.CUSTOMCONNSTR_MONGOLAB_URI ). Please try to 'console.log(process.env.CUSTOMCONNSTR_MONGOLAB_URI)' before mongo.connect. It should log something like 'mongodb://localhost/testdb'

Comment: This returns undefined

Comment: Then you have a invalid URL to your mongodb, this cannot work. Try to replace `process.env.CUSTOMCONNSTR_MONGOLAB_URI` with the String `"mongodb://localhost/mytestdb" `.

Comment: you mean this `console.log('mongodb://127.0.0.1/test');` Local server is 127.0.0.1 and test is database name

Comment: Seems to have worked but still getting the `The connection to ws://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=.... was interrupted while the page was loading.`

Comment: Sorry no... I mean this line:
    `mongo.connect("mongodb://localhost/mytestdb",function(err,db){`

PS: localhost and 127.0.0.1 is the same

Comment: Yes, thanks, I did that (with test) and seems to be okay apart from the other issue above.

Comment: Okey, do you get another error log?

Comment: Nope, just  the above error in Firefox console

Comment: Can you please try this:
`var serve = app.listen(app.get('port'))
var io = require('socket.io').listen(serve);`
instead of this:
`var serve=http.createServer(app);
var io=require('socket.io')(serve);
serve.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Ready on port ' + app.get('port'));
});`

Comment: No this made no difference. `ws://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=********** was interrupted while the page was loading.`  This seems to be issue `instance = new WebSocket(uri);`

Comment: Hmm okey, then I'm sorry... I can only give you a few tips:
- I could imagine that this `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));` destroys the socket.io connection
- I would use [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) to access mongo
- Here is a working (very basic and not nice code) socket.io chat I wrote some time: [nodejschat](https://github.com/dustin-H/nodejschat)
Have luck and sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Ahh, moment... you are not using the given socket.io client for your connection to socket.io ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  `/socket.io/socket.io.js`

Comment: The socket.io framework provides a client side [lib](http://socket.io/docs/client-api/) to connect to its server. This will not always be a websocket connection. It will perform a XHR-polling fallback connection if a websocket connection is not possible. You should connect to the server with this lib. You can use it this way: `<script src="socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
    var socket = io('http://localhost:3000/');
    socket.on('msg', function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });    
    </script>`

Comment: Still no luck, unfortunately. `var socket = io('http://localhost:3000/');

$('#send-message-btn').click(function(){
 var msg=$('#message-box').val();
 socket.emit('chat',msg);
 $('#messages').append($('<p>').text(msg));
 $('#message-box').val('');
 return false;
});
socket.on('chat',function(msg){
 $('#message').append($('<p>').text(msg));
});
`

Comment: May you can add your client side code to your question?

Comment: You don't have any html in your client side code? Where are you adding /socket.io/socket.io.js script? do you get any error in the console loading script or it isn't even in the resources list. Do you get any other errors, warnings in your browser / terminal?